# RichTextFx change selected text color and line number background

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, richtextfx

I want to change selected text's color or to change highlighting color,
and background in line numbers in  RichTextFx, but I don't know how to do it, I need your help !
[image]

Comment: please have a look at https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/tree/master/richtextfx-demos and  https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/blob/master/richtextfx-demos/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext/demo/MultiCaretAndSelectionDemo.java

Comment: and https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/wiki/RichTextFX-CSS-Reference-Guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.styled-text-area .selection {
    -fx-fill: pink;
}
```

save this as a file say `styled-text-area.css`

put this file in same package with your application class

in your class, import this file like

```
area.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styled-text-area.css").toExternalForm());
```

this will make selection color pink

by following [here](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/wiki/RichTextFX-CSS-Reference-Guide) and adding related style rules in `styled-text-area.css` you can achieve your other needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work for me... no change at all. I've overridden many other styles, and they work just fine. I wonder if there's another way.

Comment: This only changes the highlighting color. But not the text color.