# JavaFX - RichTextFX - How to change highlight text color

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, textarea, richtextfx

I am using an instance of RichTextFX's StyleClassedTextArea, but can't seem to change the color of the text itself while highlighting.

There is a similar question: [RichTextFx change selected text color and line number background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130518/richtextfx-change-selected-text-color-and-line-number-background) which has helped me, but the answer only changes the actual highlight color, not the text itself while highlighted. I want the highlighted text itself to be white so it is more-readable.

The answer from the other question is as follows:

```
.styled-text-area .selection {
    -fx-fill: pink;
}
```

I have tried other ways to get the text itself to change color such as:

```
.styled-text-area .selection .text {
    -fx-fill: white;
}


.styled-text-area .selection {
    -fx-highlight-fill: white;
}
```

But I can't seem to get anything to work. The normal -fx-text-fill syntax does not seem to work with RichTextFX.

Comment: My first guess would be `.styled-text-area .selection { -fx-text-fill: white ; }`

Comment: Yes I agree but for some reason this does not work with RichTextFX, only -fx-fill. @James_D

Comment: try to change font  color like this .styled-text-area{-fx-font-color: red;}

Answer (score 0):

you can try -rtfx-background-color: yellow;